# Number of pair of sequences of length $n$ such that no $2$ elements are equal

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My question is this :

Given two integers $n$ and $k$, we have to generate $2$ sequences $A$ and $B$ of length $n$ each containing integers from $1$ to $k$.  Find the number of sequences we can generate such that no corresponding element of sequences are equal. Formally: for each $i$ from $1$ to $n$ $: A_i \neq B_i$

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If $k < n$, the number of such permutations is $0$.  Therefore, we require that $n \geq k$.  If $n = k$, the number you seek is just the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: I am pretty sure this is an open problem.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you using "sequence" and "permutation" interchangably? Are $A$ and $B$ those permutations? If yes, are you looking to count pairs of permutations or what?

Comment: thanks @Ingix actually I don't know what I was thinking that I wrote permutation , I just meant sequences , a number can repeat itself. I'm gonna edit the question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sorry but I think now your second comment is not valid , it was valid for permutations though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each element of $A$ you have $k$ choices, so there are $k^n$ possibilities.  Given $A$, for each element of $B$ you have $k-1$ choices, so there are $(k-1)^n$ possibilities.  There are therefore $k^n(k-1)^n$ pairs possible.

Comment: It was that easy? thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like formulating the problem so other can understand it was the hard part. Your problem description still doesn't mention anything about counting pairs of sequences, for example.

Comment: Yes I'm going to edit that too. thanks again